# Get single "set" object from the list values present in the dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, list-comprehension, set-comprehension

I'm trying to build a set from the values of a dictionary. Each dictionary value is a list of strings.

```
{'a': ['a','b','c'],'b':['a','b','d'],...}
```

I am trying to use `.update(x)` to concatenate a set containing values from the dictionary. I already have success with a standard for-loop:

```
ingredientSet = set()
for values in recipes.values():
    ingredientSet.update(values)
```

What I would like to do, if possible, is to do this in a set comprehension. So far I have this:

```
ingredientSet = { ingredientSet.update(x) for x in recipes.values() }
```

but my IDE is giving me an error that "ingredientSet" is referenced before its assignment.

Is it possible to use `.update(x)` in the comprehension, or is there another way to concatenate the items into the set in a comprehension?

Comment: Don't you just want `set().union(*recipes.values())`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe This works, thank you! I guess we never learned about the `*` functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a comprehension you can do that with two `for`s like:

#### Code:

```
values_set = {item for items in data.values() for item in items}
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = {'a': ['a','b','c'],'b':['a','b','d']}

values_set = {item for items in data.values() for item in items}
print(values_set)
```

#### Result:

```
{'d', 'b', 'c', 'a'}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a functional way to achieve this using [**`itertools.chain.from_iterable(...)`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> my_dict = {'a': ['a','b','c'],'b':['a','b','d']}

>>> set(chain.from_iterable(my_dict.values()))
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
```

Also, adding here the *jonsharpe's* amswer from the comment using `set().union(...)`:

```
>>> set().union(*my_dict.values())
{'a', 'b', 'd', 'c'}
```

---

## Performance Comparison

Below is the `timeit` comparison of all the answers on Python3:

- **Using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`** - 0.558 usec per loop

  ```
  mquadri$ python3 -m timeit -s "from itertools import chain; my_dict = {'a': ['a','b','c'],'b':['a','b','d']}" "set(chain.from_iterable(my_dict.values()))"
  1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.558 usec per loop
  ```
- **Using *set comprehension*** - 0.585 usec per loop

  ```
  mquadri$ python3 -m timeit -s "from itertools import chain; my_dict = {'a': ['a','b','c'],'b':['a','b','d']}" "{item for items in my_dict.values() for item in items}"
  1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.585 usec per loop
  ```
- **Using `set().union(...)`** - 0.614 usec per loop

  ```
  mquadri$ python3 -m timeit -s "from itertools import chain; my_dict = {'a': ['a','b','c'],'b':['a','b','d']}" "set().union(*my_dict.values())"
  1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.614 usec per loop
  ```

Comment: So these are all very close from a performance point of view.  itertools can often be faster if the data set is larger.  What happens with a lot more data?